# Find the areas $A(D)$ of $D$ and $A(\sigma(D))$ of $\sigma(D)$.

Tags: differential-geometry

A regular parametrized surface $\sigma:U\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is given where $U=\lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}\mid (x,y)\neq (0,0)\rbrace$. Only the coefficients of the first fundamental form are known by
$$ 
E=1+\frac{2x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}, \quad F=\frac{2xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}, \quad G=1+\frac{2y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}.
$$
Let
$$
D=\left \{ (x,y)\in U \mid 1\leq \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq 2\wedge x\geq 0\right \}.
$$
I need to determine the area $A(D)$ of $D$ and the area $A(\sigma(D))$ of $\sigma(D)$. First we see that
$$
A(\sigma(D))=\int_{D}\left \| \sigma_{x}'\times \sigma_{y}' \right \|\, \mathrm{d}A=\int_{D}\sqrt{EG-F^{2}}\, \mathrm{d}A=\sqrt{3}\int_{D}\mathrm{d}A=\sqrt{3}A(D).
$$
So how exactly do I find $A(D)$? I've read similar about it in my book but I don't know where to start answering such exercise.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention the set $D$.

Comment: Just use elementary geometry, take the difference of the circle of radius 2 minus that of radius 1 and halve it.

Comment: The area is $3\pi$.

Comment: The answer must be $A(D)=\frac{3}{2}\pi$. If possible, could you please show me how to do using the method I have in OP?